# AmazonMQ active/standby mode failover time

Tags: amazon-web-services, activemq-classic, amazon-mq

We are using AmazonMQ setup in active/standby mode and trying to evaluate the switch over time from active to standby broker during active instance failure,
Will it be done immediately? I am using failover transport from `stomp` python client to reconnect.

Is there any SLA available for max switch over time in AmazonMQ

**Specifications**:

1). AmazonMQ -> mq.m5.large,

2). AmazonMQ active/stand-by mode,

3). Consumers application is in python (using STOMP protocol)

Answer (score 1):

Amazon mq active/standby mode does requires a promotion time to switch standby broker to active mode. Need to use Network of brokers in amazonmq for high availability